# Why is OnActionExecuting called from within OnActionExecuting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The code below was copied from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072880/asp-mvc-actionfilterattribute-onactionexecuting-not-fired).  I see in other posts the same thing, such as in the answer for this [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882916/calling-filterattributes-onactionexecuting-before-basecontrollers-onactionexec).

Why is the line `base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);` included inside the overall `OnActionExecuting` methods?

What purpose does it fulfill?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                // do some irrelevant stuff
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);           
            }

    public ActionResult Index()
            {            
                return View();
            }
}
```

Comment: I think this question might be the same as yours or at least have an answer that could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399851/why-call-base-onactionexecutingfiltercontext

Comment: to add some details here is a link to the `Controller.cs` class which `base.OnActionExecution(filterContext)` is calling. It's an empty virtual method so in your case it doesn't actually *currently* make a difference if you call it or not. However, let's say in the future you upgrade .NET versions and that upgrade includes some code in the `Controller.OnActionExecuting` method, then that new code will not be called and something very well may break. TLDR; I'd still call it even if it does nothing right now. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs

Comment: As an extended side note, .NET Core is currently under development and framework is in maintenance mode so I highly doubt any new .NET framework versions will be released and doubt you'll ever run into the specific use case mentioned above. But this is a good practice in other similar scenarios as well

Comment: @GregH I think I understand. I'm still learning how to dig deeper into the provided framework; sometimes the amount of existing code is overwhelming. Seems you're saying the framework may have code important for OnActionExecution, but it doesn't currently, so nothing happens, but if new code is added, w/o that line I'd miss it & it could cause a break.  Is it also possible new framework code could cause a break? Your comment explains it better than the post referenced in the first comment above, though that was a good reference.  Perhaps you should write it as an answer here.

Comment: @Alan your understanding is correct. Also, sure it's plausible that the new framework code could cause something to break however that situation is generally much easier to spot and fix than if you don't call `base.OnActionExecuting` and something breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

currently, the line `base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext)` does not do anything (performs no work). The functional behavior will be the same with or without the line.

**Longer answer:**

The .NET source code for `Controller.OnActionExecuting` looks as follows (taken from [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs)):

```
protected virtual void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
}
```

If you look at the `OnActionExecuting` method, you'll see this method is completely empty. This is the code/method that `base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext)` is calling. You don't *have* to call `base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext)` as it currently does nothing however I would recommend doing so. The reason behind this is that if .NET framework is updated such that the `Controller.OnActionExecuting` method actually has needed code it in it, then the needed code will not be called without including the line in question. This could lead to some scenarios that can be pretty difficult and time-consuming to debug. It's also certainly possible for new framework code to be introduced that does break your code when you call `base.OnActionExecuting` however this scenario is generally easier to spot and fix than the other. Of course in the end, it's all going to come down to what code the framework introduces and what it breaks for how easy it is to identify and resolve.

As a side-note, .NET framework is in maintenance mode now so I highly doubt the example I mentioned above with .NET framework updating the code in `Controller.OnActionExecuting` will ever happen however it serves as a good best practice in other similar scenarios as well.